# Why do I keep printing out the memory address instead of array values?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to print out an array of 2d arrays (you can think of the whole thing as a 3d array) where the user decides the size of the outer array, as well as rows and column size of the 2d inner arrays. I've now made 2 functions, one to initialize the arrays and one to print them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

    int arrays, rows, columns;
    int ***tables;

    printf("\nEnter the number of arrays (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%d", &arrays);

    while (arrays !=0){
        printf("\n Enter values for rows, columns (e.g: 2 3): ");
        scanf("%d %d", &rows, &columns);

        tables = (int ***) calloc (arrays, sizeof (int**));
        initarrays(tables, arrays, rows, columns);
        printarrays(tables, arrays, rows, columns);

        printf("Enter the number of arrays (0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &arrays);
    }
    return 0;
}

void initarrays(int ***nTables, int nArrs, int row, int column){
    for (int i = 0; i < nArrs; i++){
        nTables[i] = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));

        if (nTables[i] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of Memory");
            exit (0);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            nTables[i][j] = (int *)malloc(column * sizeof(int));
            if (nTables[i][j] == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of Memory");
                exit (0);
            }
        }
    }

    // Assign values to allocate memory for each array except for last
    for (int i = 0; i < nArrs; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < column; k++){
                nTables[i][j][k] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //Assign values for last array
    for (int i = nArrs; i < nArrs+1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < column; k++){
                nTables[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // free up allocated memeory
    for (int i = 0; i < nArrs; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            free(nTables[i][j]);
        }
        free (nTables[i]);
    }
    free(nTables);
}

void printarrays(int ***nTables, int nArrs, int row, int column){
    // print out the values in the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < nArrs; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < column; k++){
                printf("%2i ",nTables[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Within the outer array, I need to make sure the last 2d array is one that is full of 0s, whereas the preceding ones are full of 1s. I'm not sure if one of my pointers is incorrect, my memory allocation is off, or my iteration is wrong when initializing, but for some reason, my output is always a mix of memory addresses and array values instead of just the array values that I need them to be. I basically want to print several 2d arrays of 1s, and then one more array with 0s. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: `// free up allocated memeory` Why are you surprised that printing after freeing it all would result in unexpected behaviour?

Comment: `for (int i = nArrs; i < nArrs+1; i++)` is wrong. Think about what the last valid index of `nTables` is. But worse, `initarrays` frees all the space. So nothing remains allocated when `printarrays` is called.

Comment: `initarrays` allocates memory and then frees it right away. That's pretty pointless.

Comment: @EricPostpischil gotcha. i added 1 to the iteration for the ntables[i] malloc and deleted the free space, and it worked. But then where should i free the space? at the end of the program, yes?

Comment: You can free the space after you are done using it. In many programs, there is no point in freeing memory only at the end of the program, because the operating system will free all resources the program was using, in general-purpose multiuser operating systems. By freeing memory earlier, you release it earlier.

Comment: Some parts of that are a bit complicated. Small allocations are likely only to free the memory within your own process, because they are clustered with other allocations your program may still be using. But freeing them makes them available for other parts of your program to reuse, so your program will use less memory than if it kept allocating new memory all the time without freeing any of it. Freeing large allocations may result in memory pages being released from the process, so the operating system can reuse them for other purposes. A lot depends on the operating system.